# How to Do These File Operations(Move all files in specified folders to upper folder and delete these folders) Using CMD

Tags: cmd.exe, files-folders

Imagine that we have a folder structure like this.

```
Music
-Artist 1
--Song1
--Song2
--Song3
..
-Artist 2
--Unknown Album
---Song1
---Song2
---Song3
..
-Artist 3
--Song1
--Song2
-Artist 4
--Unknown Album
---Song1
---Song2
---Song3
..
....
```

In a folder named 'Music' I want to move all files under folders named 'Unknown Album' to upper level and delete these folders.

After this operation folder structure should look like this:

```
Music
-Artist 1
--Song1
--Song2
--Song3
..
-Artist 2
--Song1
--Song2
--Song3
..
-Artist 3
--Song1
--Song2
-Artist 4
--Song1
--Song2
--Song3
..
....
```

I'm talking about 1TB+ music archive. How can I do this with CMD ?

Comment: 'To upper level' isn't specific enough.  Whatever the answer, this will be tricky but quite do-able with batch but will require some advanced batch skills.  Also.. BE AWARE, I HAVE DONE BATCH PROCESSING ON 1tb archives.  Every time an artist has `&` in the name like `Hall & Oats` (I know.. I know.. it was all I could think of..) YOU BATCH WILL BARF ON THE `&`.  I had to first rename all `&` to `and` before processing the rest of the tree.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /r %i in ("unknown album\*.*") do move "%i" "%~pi.."
```

This will move all files under folders named "unknown album" to upper folder.

```
for /d /r . %d in (unknown album) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"
```

This will delete all folders named "unknown album".